# JavaScript library to create railroad-style grammar diagrams

Tags: library, javascript, web-services

I am looking for a JavaScript library to create railroad diagrams similar to those at [json.org](http://json.org) and [h2 database grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html):

[image: railroad diagram]

Comment: Preferring a JS library. A ws would work depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for Tab Atkins' **[railroad-diagrams](https://github.com/tabatkins/railroad-diagrams)**.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Just what I was after.